# Start Two Instances of Same Project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to develop a multiplayer game in C++ with MSVC 2010, and I want to have it open two debuggable instances of my exe when I hit Start Debugging.

Comment: start a new instance of visual studio 2010

Answer (score 1):

You can right click a project in your solution and select Debug > Start new instance to load multiple instances at once.